# is there a way to log/see a javascript local variable without using breakpoints in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to log a local variable in an external script that is called on the page. If I place a breakpoint I can see its values, but it becomes inaccessible if I make the code start again. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi, maybe I don´t understand your question, but is it console.log(*variableName*) your looking for? The variable/object will be printed in the console.

Comment: To better clarify, I'm asking if it's possibile to log a local variable without stopping the code execution, like in this case https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default#Wrong_scope

Answer (score 1):

that's how you do it `console.log(variablename);`